# Call function after Vuetify v-bottom-sheet transition completes? Async vuex mutation? async computed property?

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, vuetify.js, vuex

I've built a modal using Vuex and Vuetify's `v-bottom-sheet`. Basically how it works is when the state of `sendMessageModal` is true it is picked up in a computed property and shows the modal and vice versa for false:

```
//Vuex mutation

toggleSendMessageModal(state) {
    return state.sendMessageModal = ! state.sendMessageModal;
}

//Vuex Action

closeSendMessageModal(context) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    context.commit('toggleSendMessageModal');

    setTimeout(1000);
    const error = false;

    if(!error){
        resolve();
    } else {
        reject();
    }
    });
}

//SendMessageModal Component

computed: {
    showSendMessageModal() {
        return this.$store.state.sendMessageModal;
    }
},
methods: {
    closeSendMessageModal(){
        this.$store.dispatch('closeSendMessageModal').then(function() {
            this.clearValues()
        }.bind(this));
    },
    clearValues: function(){
        this.subject = '';
        this.body = '';
        this.slide = 1;
    },
}
```

What I'm trying to do is `clearValues()` **after** the modal is closed. The only way I can currently do this is if I set a time out like such:

```
//SendMessageModal Component
closeSendMessageModal(){

    this.$store.dispatch('closeSendMessageModal').then(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){ this.clearValues(); }.bind(this), 1000);
        
    }.bind(this));
},
```

But I'd like to wait for the modal to close then `clearValues()`. The problem is if someone wants to reopen the modal immediately again.

Note there is a transition on the modal, but I think what's going on is the `toggleSendMessageModal` isn't allowing for the modal to close then clear values.

Gif of CSS transition from Vuetify.  And [here](https://gist.github.com/corbin88/81b131eae006ce3a5315853b98098dec) is my full component code.

[image]

**Edit 2**

I don't know if this is a vuetify problem.

I set the time out on the `closeSendMessageModal` action:

```
closeSendMessageModal(context) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    //context.commit('toggleSendMessageModal');

    setTimeout(function(){ context.commit('toggleSendMessageModal'); }.bind(this), 1000);

    const error = false;

    if(!error){
        resolve();
    } else {
        reject();
    }
    });
}
```

The `this.clearValues();` method is still hitting before the `closeSendMessageModal()` action has been resolved.

Comment: Edited post with gif

Comment: I'm sorry I can't get to the transition since it's using the vuetify library. Is there something else I could do?

Comment: [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/corbin88/81b131eae006ce3a5315853b98098dec)

Comment: SetTimeout does work, but the problem I see is if someone wants to reopen the modal immediately again.

Comment: btw, it's still not clear why you want to wait, i don't think that's ever mentioned in your question.  and the only problem in the gif seems to be the setTimeout delay

Comment: It's just not the most ascetically appealing thing to have the slide switch before the modal closes like it does in the last frame of the gif. Sorry the gif really seems to rush through the problem at the last bit

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a question than an answer but could be both. Cant you use nextTick for this? e.g.:

```
methods: {
    closeSendMessageModal(){
        this.$store.dispatch('closeSendMessageModal');
        this.$nextTick(() => this.clearValues());
    },
    clearValues: function(){
        this.subject = '';
        this.body = '';
        this.slide = 1;
    },
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the same thing keeps happening, thanks for the help

Comment: Your transition is not waiting on slide to be 1 right? or anything to do with slide?

Comment: No, basically on the closing slide `slide = 2` what I want is the slide to stay on slide 2 until closed and change to slide one after `this.clearValues()`